# Posting more than one picture on Facebook integration

Tags: android, facebook

I am dealing with Facebook integration on Android. I posted simple text along with a picture on a Facebook wall. Is it possible to post more than one picture? Can anyone suggest a link which might explain this? I used http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-update-facebook-status-via.html for posting both text and a picture.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot post more than one pic for a post. So one post can have maximum one picture.

If we really want to post more than one image for a post, you can club those images into one image and post it on wall.

Comment: I mean, you create new image using many images. and use the new image to post on wall. You can find GD library for JAVA.